# How can use dialog box with all list item in listview

Tags: android

hi i am developing an application in which i am using a list.In this list view each item is appearing with button by clicking on this a dialog box is opening which has two elements edit and delete.how can we do this

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    l2 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout2);
    l3 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout3);
    l4 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout4);



    l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    l4.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (z[0] == 1) {
                l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                z[0] = 0;
            } else {
                l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                z[0] = 1;
            }
        }
    });

    t2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(z[1]==1){
                l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                z[1]=0;
            }
            else {
                l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                z[1]=1;
            }

        }
    });
    t3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(z[2]==1){
                l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                z[2]=0;
            }
            else {

                l3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                z[2]=1;
            }


        }
    });
    t4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(z[3]==1){
                l4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                z[3]=0;
            }
            else {

                l4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                z[3]=1;
            }
        }
    });

<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#F9BB5A"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <EditView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/choose"
                android:text="Choose one option"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"/>



            </RelativeLayout>
```

similarly make more relative layout...
hope it helps you..